# Unknown characters showing up in decompressed string via gzip

Tags: java, node.js, gzip

I have a mobile app where I am compressing a JSON string via gzip and storing the data in a database. I also have a web app that decompresses that same JSON string to display data on a web page. The problem is that the JSON string seems to have some unknown characters show up when decompressed in the web app that are not seen when decompressing in the mobile app.

The Android app is written in Java and uses the following code to compress the string:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = null;
try {
    gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(gzipOut);
    objectOut.writeObject(jsonData);
    objectOut.close();

    // Wrapper for the byte array
    ServerData nData = new ServerData();
    nData.data = baos.toByteArray();
    String finalData = JSONObjectStringConverter.json.toJson(nData);
    return finalData;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above seems to work correctly, storing the byte array within the wrapper and then into the database.

The web app uses a nodejs backend and uses the following code to decompress the data after it is retrieved from the database and removed from the wrapper:

```
try{
   // Convert the byte array back to JSON 
    const decompressedData = zlib.gunzipSync(new Uint8Array(compressedByteArray) );
    jsonData = optionDataInflated.toString();
}catch(e){
    console.error(e)
}
```

Again, this mostly seems to work but there are some unidentified characters at the beginning of the string:

```
"��\u0000\u0005t��{\"cloudData\": ..."
```

I thought it may have something to do with the header of the compressed string (i.e. the first 10 bytes in the byte array):

```
[31, -117, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
```

but I wasn't able to make much progress on that end. Does anyone have any other suggestions as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectOutputStream is part of a general Java object serialization mechanism, and you're going to have a hard time making it work with nodejs.

Get rid of the object stream and write your JSON directly to the gzip stream. Assuming jsonData is a string, use:

```
gzipOut.write(jsonData.getBytes("UTF8"));
gzipOut.close();
```